# Add event to multiple calendars

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, calendar, microsoft-outlook-2016

Is it possible to add an event to multiple calendars in Outlook (2016), without copying and pasting?

I have certain events that are not fully supported by the Outlook.com calendar.  For instance, recurring events that follow a non-gregorian calendar.

So I need to keep them in pst form, where I can back them up locally and restore if necessary.

On the other hand, I would like them to be also in ost, so I can sync them to the Outlook.com calendar.

I thought the best solution would be to add my events to both calendars simultaneously.  Any ideas on how I can accomplish that?